# PHP: create image with ImagePng and convert with base64_encode in a single file?

Tags: php, image, gd

I have created an image with ImagePng(). I dont want it to save the image to the file system but want to output it on the same page as base64 encode inline Image, like

```
print '<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(ImagePng($png)).'" alt="image 1" width="96" height="48"/></p>';
```

which does not work.

Is this possible in a single PHP file at all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 36):

The trick here will be to use output buffering to capture the output from `imagepng()`, which either sends output to the browser or a file. It doesn't return it to be stored in a variable (or base64 encoded):

```
// Enable output buffering
ob_start();
imagepng($png);
// Capture the output and clear the output buffer
$imagedata = ob_get_clean();

print '<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($imagedata).'" alt="image 1" width="96" height="48"/></p>';
```

This is adapted from a user example in [the `imagepng()` docs.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)

Answer (score 5):

I had trouble using the ob_get_contents() when using PHP with AJAX, so I tried this:

```
$id = generateID(); //Whereas this generates a random ID number
$file="testimage".$id.".png";
imagepng($image, $file);
imagedestroy($image);
echo(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
unlink($file);
```

This saves a temporary image file on the server and then it is removed after it is encoded and echoed out.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to store to an explicit file, and you are already using `ob_start()` for something else (so you cannot use ob_start for this case without a lot of refactoring), you can define your own stream wrapper that store a stream output to a variable.

You use `stream_wrapper_register` to register a new stream wrapper, and implement its `stream_write` method to write it to a variable whose value you can retrieve later. Then you pass this stream (actually you just need to pass the URI for this stream) to `imagepng`. `imagepng` wanting to close your stream won't bother you, as long as your stream wrapper doesn't destroy the data when it is closed (`stream_close` method called).

Comment: This should be preferred over using a file or output buffering.