# Display png image from php on a certain position on a webpage

Tags: php, php-gd

The code works fine if i display only image with the help of code.

```
 <?php
 // my code processing
  header("Content-type: image/png");
   imagepng($base_image);
   ?>
```

But if i use some other fields like echo some text or i want to put some buttons on my page.
I get error, for code:

```
    <?php
echo "hi";

?>


 <?php
 // my code processing
  header("Content-type: image/png");
   imagepng($base_image);
   ?>
```

It gives me error : The displayed page contains some errors.
Can someone please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any output before the `Content-Type` header will break your code. The browser does not know you are trying to serve it an image since it will have already defaulted to `text/html` by the time your image data turns up. If you want an image at a given point in your page, you will need to serve it as a separate object. The easiest way is to wrap it in an `<img>` tag e.g. `<img src="myimage_generator.php" />`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based off of [another SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370847/php-create-image-with-imagepng-and-convert-with-base64-encode-in-a-single-file) Your problem is that you're trying to send header info after you already sent data to the browser, which is not possible. Even so you can't display an image on a page with it's data alone. You need to base64 encode the image data first. This way you can build a whole HTML page and place this image anywhere on it and position it with CSS.

```
// Enable output buffering
ob_start();
imagepng($base_image);
// Capture the output
$imagedata = ob_get_contents();
// Clear the output buffer
ob_end_clean();

echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($imagedata).'">';
```