# imagepng: how to save the output in a variable and then display it using img tag

Tags: php

I want to save the output of the imagepng to a variable instead of dispaying it, and then want to use variable in a img tag to display the image.How can I do this?

I am using a smarty template for that I need to save the resultant image to variabe and then display it in a smarty template tpl file

Thanks it advance

Comment: make that variable Global, you can use session/cookie for this. Explain more

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just point your image tag `src` at the image-generating PHP script and have it output the image.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370847/php-create-image-with-imagepng-and-convert-with-base64-encode-in-a-single-file

Comment: @Utkanos  I am using smarty for that I need to save it in a variable and then display it in a tpl file

Answer (score 12):

`imagepng` — Output a PNG image to either the browser or a file

Try as below :

```
ob_start();
imagepng($png);
$imagedata = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($imagedata).'"/>';
```

Comment: Can be shorter, just `ob_start(); imagepng($png); $imagedata = ob_get_clean();` - then you don't need to call the `ob_end_clean();`

Answer (score 0):

Try using streams. Implement a stream wrapper that saves the contents written into a variable, and pass a stream of this type into `imagepng`.

For more details, see [image outputs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php#refsect1-function.imagepng-seealso).