# How to create the smallest possible transparent png/gif of a given size in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing, png, gif

I've made this code to generate the data-uri for a transparent PNG of a given size:

```
function createTransparentDataURI($w = 1, $h = 1) {

    // Enable output buffering
    ob_start();

    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    imagesavealpha($img, true);
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($img, 0, 0, $color);
    imagepng($img);
    imagedestroy($img);

    // Capture the output
    $imagedata = ob_get_contents();
    // Clear the output buffer
    ob_end_clean();

    // REF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370847/php-create-image-with-imagepng-and-convert-with-base64-encode-in-a-single-file
    return 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($imagedata);
}
```

An example run with

```
echo createTransparentDataURI(1016, 312);
```

returns

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA/gAAAE4CAYAAADvrFgKAAAE40lEQVR4nO3BAQ0AAADCoPdPbQ8HFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwZltVAAEv7IggAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

Is there any way to "compress" (PNG is lossless, but with a compression option?) this data-uri with a better encoding or using a single-color GIF? Programmatic graphics with PHP isn't my strongest area.

Comment: Here is the good news. Your original PNG is 1308 bytes, but simply re-saving it with Photoshop as a 2-color GIF brings the size down to 918 bytes, and, even better, re-saving it as a 2-color PNG brings it down to just 459 bytes. (That includes a 37-byte stamp, even though I *specifically* told PS to not save it.) An obvious first optimization would be to *not* create your image as "32-bit RGB+alpha", but with a lower color depth instead.

Comment: @RadLexus That's good to know it's possible to bring the size down. These dummy images are being made on-the-fly/cached to be inlined with  some eventual HTML. They have to be done in PHP without CLI. Any suggestions to modify the code in my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that the image will be transparent and nothing will appear on it you don't need it to be lossless. This means you can use a color palette of single color which will create a index for this color and use the index for all pixels in the image. To create index palette PNG you should use the `imagetruecolortopalette()` function in your code: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagetruecolortopalette.php

You can also set the image compression level to highest.

```
function createTransparentDataURI($w = 1, $h = 1) {
    //...
    //create image palette with one color, the dithering (the second argument) doesn't matter here
    imagetruecolortopalette($img, false, 1);
    imagepng($img, null, 9); //set the compression level to highest
    //...
}
```

This reduced the data length of image 1016x312 from 1308 to 133 bytes, which is almost by factor of ten.

By converting the binary data to base64 you can see with naked eye that there is room to compress that too:

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA/gAAAE4AQMAAADVYspJAAAAA1BMVEUEAgSVKDOdAAAAPUlEQVR42u3BAQ0AAADCoPdPbQ8HFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/BicAAABWZX81AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

*where the multiple "A"s are*

You can enable the http's server gzip compression, to compress this response further more.

GIF wouldn't do better as it's size in my test was 910 bytes.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! It works like a charm. Many thanks.